# Continuous Functions with countably many jump discontinuitites

Tags: functional-analysis, measurable-functions, piecewise-continuity

Let $X$ be the set of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which can be written as
$$
f = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f_i I_{[a_i,b_i]},
$$
where $a_i<b_i$, $f_i$ is continuous, but $f$ need not be continuous at $a_i$ (or $b_i$).  What can be said about this set of functions (ex do they contain all $L^p$ functions etc...)

More generally, if $X$ is the set of all functions from $\mathbb{R}^k$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ with at most $\mathfrak{c}$ many discontinuities, does $X$ contain the set of measurable functions?

Comment: Having（at most) uncountably discontinuities sounds like a valid property for all functions. Did you mean having at most $\mathfrak c$ discontinuities instead?

Comment: @fantasie yes!  Where $\mathfrak{c}$ is the continuum?

Comment: My mind was messed up a little bit, and now I realize that points of discontinuity is a subset of $\mathbb R^k$; therefore, its cardinality is not greater than $\mathfrak c$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ be a nowhere continuous bounded function on $[0,1]$. This function belongs to $L^p(\Bbb R)$, yet it does not belong to $X$.

Edit:  this function needs to be measurable, but the result still holds.

Comment: Good old Baire saves the day again :) nice answer.

Comment: I thought I knew how to prove that a nowhere continuous bounded function does not belong to $X$. However, I realized that the standard Baire argument does not apply when we deal with pointwise limits of functions with finitely many discontinuities. For example $1_{\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]}\in X$. Of course for this silly example, we have that there exists a continuous representative (just changing on null sets). But I am not so sure anymore that we can exclude evil things from happening